# Playing my hls stream is freezing - why so?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, vlc, libvlc

Hello I'm try to play my hls stream [http://81.25.234.43:8083/tv/1plus1HD/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9Mi8xNi8yMDIxIDI6MTE6MjcgUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1GYjhMdlVJdUh1OHVsQ05hSVFTWjBBPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTYwNDgwMCZpZD0zMQ==](http://81.25.234.43:8083/tv/1plus1HD/l_248987_90132242_102686.ts?nimblesessionid=298547&wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9Mi8xNi8yMDIxIDI6MTY6NDQgUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT11aGh2SExSekwxU0szNEFQeklEbTR3PT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTYwNDgwMCZpZD0zNg==)

via LibVLC android

```
api "org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:3.3.0-eap17"
```

but video is always freezing while playing and i got in logs

```
libvlc video output: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 53 ms)
```

My codes

```
    class VlcMediaPlayer(context: Context) : IVLCVout.Callback {

    private val libVLCFactory = FactoryManager.getFactory(ILibVLCFactory.factoryId) as ILibVLCFactory
    private val factory = FactoryManager.getFactory(IMediaFactory.factoryId) as IMediaFactory

    private val options = ArrayList<String>().apply {
        add("-vvv");
        add("--avcodec-dr");
        add("--clock-jitter=1500");
        add("--live-caching=1500");
        add("--network-caching=1500");
        add("--file-caching=3000");
        add("--no-drop-late-frames");
        add("--no-skip-frames");
        add("--no-sout-smem-time-sync");
        add("--sout-mp4-faststart");
        add("--sout-x264-partitions=fast");
        add("--adaptive-logic=nearoptimal");
        add("--adaptive-use-access");
        add("--avcodec-threads=10");
        add("--sout-x264-psy");
        add("--aout=opensles");
        add("--demuxdump-append");
        add("--avcodec-hw=d3d11va");
    }

    private val sLibVLC = libVLCFactory.getFromOptions(context, VLCOptions.libOptions)

    private val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer(sLibVLC).apply {
        vlcVout.addCallback(this@VlcMediaPlayer)
    }

    override fun onSurfacesCreated(vlcVout: IVLCVout?) {
    }

    override fun onSurfacesDestroyed(vlcVout: IVLCVout?) {
    }

    @MainThread
    fun setVideoScale(scale: Float) {
        mediaPlayer.scale = scale
    }

    fun setVideoAspectRatio(aspect: String?) {
        mediaPlayer.aspectRatio = aspect
    }

    @MainThread
    fun setSurface(surface: Surface, holder: SurfaceHolder?) {
//        mediaPlayer.stop()
        //mediaPlayer.release()

        mediaPlayer.vlcVout.apply {
            setVideoSurface(surface, holder)
            attachViews(null)
        }

        //release()
    }

    fun setWindowsSize(width: Int, height: Int) {
        mediaPlayer.vlcVout.setWindowSize(width, height)
    }

    fun setMedia(uri: Uri) {
        val media = factory.getFromUri(sLibVLC, uri)
        options.forEach {
            media.addOption(it)
        }
        mediaPlayer.media = media
    }

    fun play() = mediaPlayer.play()

    fun stop() = mediaPlayer.stop()

    fun release() {
        mediaPlayer.release()
    }
}
```

Comment: `--avcodec-hw=d3d11va` this looks very wrong if you're running on Android. Where did you find these options?

Comment: @mfkl Without this options too playing video with freezing